# Can't change filter on a pivot table - python win32

Tags: python, winapi, filter

With the code below I'm simply trying to open an Excel Sheet called "POS Refresh" and clear the filters on "Daily RR Flag" field.

```
    import win32com.client
    xlapp = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
    xlapp.DisplayAlerts = False
    wb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open('H:/POS Refresh.xlsx')
    ws = wb.Worksheets['Sheet1']
    pvtTable = wb.Sheets('Sheet1').Range("A10").PivotTable
    pvtTable.PivotFields('Daily RR Flag').ClearAllFilters()
    xlapp.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone()
    ws.PivotTables('PivotTable1').PivotCache().Refresh()
    wb.Save()
    xlapp.Quit()
    del xlapp
```

However I get the error

```
   "Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\PABRAMOW\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Test Refresh win32 one 
    pivot only.py", line 8, in <module> pvtTable.PivotFields('Daily RR 
    Flag').ClearAllFilters()
    File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 2, in PivotFields
    pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 
    'PivotFields method of PivotTable class failed', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)
```

No matter which filter in that pivot table I'm trying to clear I get 'PivotFields method of PivotTable class failed'.

Do you know what may be the reason and what else I could try? I think it has to be related to the pivot table itself which is based on big data source. If I create a very small and simple pivot table the code runs without errors and filters are cleared correctly.

Comment: I figured out it has to do with the name of the Pivot Field. Since I use external connection for the pivot table the displayed name "Daily RR Flag" is not exactly the PivotField name so it's not recognized. Can anyone help with printing all PivotField names in win32com?

Comment: I tried a simple :  

    for pvtField in pvtTable.PivotFields:
    print (pvtField.Name)'

but I get the error:  

    for pvtField in pvtTable.PivotFields:
    TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable